# find ... | xargs grep --> colors missing for output of grep

Tags: grep, colors, xargs

This way I get colored output:

```
grep class testdata.py
```

Since this gets set in my .bashrc:

```
alias grep='grep -n --color'
```

But if I search like this, I see no colored output:

```
find -name '*.py'  | xargs grep "class"
```

Has someone an idea how to enable colored output of `grep` if called via `find ...| xargs grep`?

Comment: Because xargs does not know about your aliases.

Answer (score 8):

You have to add `--color` explicitly because `xargs` doesn't use your aliases, as mentioned in the comments. So your command would look like:

```
find -name '*.py'  | xargs grep --color "class"
```